# What is the most performant way to store an image as base64 dataURL?

Tags: javascript, django, postgresql

I am using Django 3.0 with PostgreSQL 12.

I need to store an image and render it on a page as base64 for use in a javascript function.

Is it more performant to:

- store the image as `TextField` and save the raw base64 in the database
- store the image as a file on the server (using `filefield`), and convert the image **server side** to base64 before returning it in `context`
- store the image as a file on the server, and convert the image **client side** to base64?

The images are all <10kb big, and typically would be less than 50 per page. However there may be a large number of page loads with concurrent users.

Comment: This question is off-topic for StackOverflow format but in most scenarios option 1 would be the best compromise. In #2 and #3 you are transferring approximately the same amount of data (maybe 25% less in ideal conditions, more like 5% for [real world usage](https://lemire.me/blog/2019/01/30/what-is-the-space-overhead-of-base64-encoding/)) from the server to the client, but you need to do extra processing to convert it to base64.